# Force a sum to be simplified

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation

I want to force this sum to be simplified to 1

```
Sum[Cos[(Pi*l*(2*m + 1))/(n + 1)], {l, 0, n}]
```

Only DiscretePlot3D gives the correct result showing all point to 1

Comment: For what values of $n$ and $m$?

Comment: @MarcoB for any integer number of n and m

Answer (score 9):

Wrapping the first argument of `Sum` with [`TrigToExp`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrigToExp.html) gives the desired result:

```
FullSimplify[Sum[TrigToExp[Cos[Pi*l*(2*m + 1)/(n + 1)]], {l, 0, n}], m ∈ Integers]
```

> 1

Comment: Great answer. Thank you @kgir

Comment: @Nitra, you are most welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Another way:

If I use:

```
Exp[I x] // Re // ComplexExpand

(*Cos[x]*)
```

then:

```
func = Sum[Exp[I*(Pi*l*(2*m + 1))/(n + 1)], {l, 0, n}] // Re // ComplexExpand;
FullSimplify[func, Assumptions -> {n ∈ Integers, m ∈ Integers}]

(* 1 *)
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The following code might do what you want:

```
s0 = Sum[Cos[(Pi*l*(2*m + 1))/(n + 1)], {l, 0, n}] // Simplify;
s1 = s0 /. {Cos[X_] - Cos[Y_] -> 2 Sin[(X + Y)/2] Sin[(Y - X)/2]};
s2 = s1 /. {Sin[x_] :> Sin[Factor@x], 
            Csc[x_] :> -Sin[(m + 1/2) Pi]/Sin[(m Pi - x)]};
s3 = Simplify[s2, m \[Element] Integers]
```

which evaluates to `1`. The step to `s1` was easy, but I had to do lots of experimentation to find the steps to `s2` and `s3`. In particular the rule
`Csc[x_] :> -Sin[(m + 1/2) Pi]/Sin[(m Pi - x)]` assumes that `m` is an integer but I could not get Mathematica to do it automatically. There may be better ways to simplify the sum `s0` but perhaps others can produce them.

Comment: Good work. Thank you.